# Wrong resource controller URL when binding a service to a cloud function

Tags: command-line-interface, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

I have defined an IBM Cloud Function action and am trying to bind an existing IoT service to it using CLI, as [described in documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/binding_services.html#binding_services):

```
ibmcloud fn service bind iotf-service myActionName
```

The task fails with the error:

> error: Unable to query services of the target resource group 'some-id':
>
> Get `https://resource-controller.ibm.com/v1/resource_instances?resource_group_id=some-id&resource_id=&resource_plan_id=`: dial tcp: lookup resource-controller.ibm.com on 8.8.4.4:53: no such host

which is in a way understandable, because, according to the [IBM Cloud resource controller documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/resource-controller), its endpoint hostname is in fact `resource-controller.cloud.ibm.com`, not `resource-controller.ibm.com`.

I made sure that my Cloud Functions plugin is of the latest version. Clearly its configuration has the resource controller URL wrong.

I failed to find any references to the resource controller in the CLI configuration files.

How can I tell the cloud functions plugin to use the correct resource controller URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, try setting the `ibmcloud` API endpoint to a region specific value.  For example, in the us-south region, set the ibmcloud API to `api.ng.bluemix.net`

```
ibmcloud api api.ng.bluemix.net
```